# Properly handling image resizing in web slider

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have [a web slider](http://farosafety.azurewebsites.net/) with an image in it. I've asked my designers for an image of the highest possible dimensions that I'd like to support (1920x1080 browser window).

This looks great at the highest resolution, but as the browser window gets smaller and smaller the image doesn't scale appropriately. I'm not sure what techniques I should be performing to make sure an image like the one in the example above is scaled down appropriately as the window size changes.

Should I ask for various resolutions of the same image from our designer? And swap out the image using media queries in css? Or is there some other way to properly do this in CSS using background image size, etc?

Edit:

So the image was created with text and graphics. The problem may be that there's no way to support this on various device sizes. How do other people/companies handle images with text/graphics as part of the image, and not over on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Applying max-height:100% & max-width:100% to the element you wish to remain scaled.
I.E

```
<div class ="wrapper">
<div class ="image"> 
</div>
</div>

CSS
.image{
max-height:100%
max-width:100%
}
```